# How to add Data in experience builder in community?

Tags: customer-community, community-builder, partner-communities, experience-builder-page

[image]

I have added a component i.e my profile so it shows that its not supported by any data so how can i add the data over here?

Comment: This will show me You can't access this profile right now. Try again in a few minutes.

Comment: Yes i got the data thank you

Comment: So it's working OK now? Did you simply set the User Id property as per the other question's answer?

Comment: No actually currentUserId provides me the data of current user but i want the data of that particular user who has logged in the community

Comment: That's what the user will see when they view this page. The builder is there to create and edit the pages. You can't see what another user is going to see...